# Laravel excel custom storage path

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I created a command that fills .csv and stores it in /storage/app. I need to make a custom path to let's say my downloads directory. Tried like that:

```
$responce = Excel::store(new ClientProviderSport($compliance), $fileName, 'local', '/Downloads', \Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::CSV);
```

My export file looks like this:

```
protected $invoices;

    public function __construct(array $invoices)
    {
        $this->invoices = $invoices;
    }

    public function array(): array
    {
        return $this->invoices;
    }
    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'Client ID',
            'Client Name',
            'Number of Provider',
            'Number of Sports',
            'Sports'
        ];
    }
```

And finally my filesystems.php looks like this:

```
'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
    ],
```

I am given this error:

```
touch(): Unable to create file /home/user/reports/.dev/phpLaravel/storage/framework/cache/laravel-excel/laravel-excel-Hmbk3Yss26wjL4rRwfCMFfC7PiMls3PI./storage because No such file or directory
```

Any and all help gratefully received.

Comment: so what is the issue?

Comment: I'm given this error: touch(): Unable to create file /path/ because No such file or directory

Comment: add the errors in the question

Comment: @Yorkata008 you mean outside the laravel storage folder?

Comment: @Seyid yes in my /home/user/Downloads if that is possible